# I need to sign the active user on a windows 10 pc off through java, I already have the basic CMD queries I need, I just don't know how to use them?

Tags: java, cmd

The block of text at the bottom of this post is a template of a method based on other commands I have built into my app, those other commands work fine and so does this one if I first use query user in CMD to find out what the user name is and then replace  with the username or ID.
But I'd like this method to ask for the ID of the active user and then sign them out, without me needing to hold its hand.

For further context, this command in CMD `quser /server:helpdesk` returns the following:

```
USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 <5 char username>    rdp-tcp#5           5  Active          .  2023/02/27 12:32
```

The users I will be forcing off will always have a 5 digit username and I am a domain admin so user rights will not be an issue.

Explanation of my variables:

- HorIP is a text field for host name or IP of the PC
- panel is the active panel, either having text field or check boxes in them
- cmdsend list of all commands that I will run

Here is the method so far:

```
public void signout (JPanel panel){
    List<String> cmdsend = new ArrayList<>();
    if (panel == CustomDevice_Panel) {
        cmdsend.add("logoff <USER>  /SERVER:" + HorIP.getText());
    } else  {
        for (Component c : panel.getComponents()) {
            if (c instanceof JCheckBox checkBox) {
                if (checkBox.getToolTipText() != null) {
                    if (checkBox.isSelected())  {
                        cmdsend.add("logoff <USER>  /SERVER:" + checkBox.getToolTipText());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    try  {
        for (int i = 0; i < cmdsend.size(); i++)  {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdsend.get(i));
        }
    } catch (IOException ex)  {
        System.out.println("failed");
    }
}
```

Haven't tried much yet, but I imagine that there would be a way to use the results of a quser command to put a user into the logoff command, just not sure how though.

Comment: If you can get the session ID of the currently logged in user by using cmd (for example, with `query user %USERNAME% | findstr /R "^%USERNAME% .*>"
`, why not continue along that path and use `logoff <session_id>` ?

Comment: @FiddlingAway unfortunately I don't know enough about cmd to do that, which is why I asked for help.
Although, I amusingly go what I needed from ChatGPT. It kept giving me nonsense, but it lead me closer and closer and I eventually got to my solution. I'll post what I am using now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked ChatGPT for help.. And of course it kept giving me nonsense, but after harassing it for a while I managed to piece together something that does the job. For those who wish to know, here's my solution:

It changed from one to two methods, one to populate a list with all the host names / IP addresses, then that method tells the second method to sign the active user of the PCs off one at a time...

```
public void signoutprep (JPanel panel){
    List<String> toSignout = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> toSignoutm = new ArrayList<>();
    if (panel == CustomDevice_Panel)
    {
        toSignout.add(HorIP.getText());
    } 
    else 
    {
        for (Component c : panel.getComponents())
        {
            if (c instanceof JCheckBox checkBox)
            {
                if (checkBox.getToolTipText() != null)
                {
                    if (checkBox.isSelected()) 
                    {
                        toSignout.add(checkBox.getToolTipText());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < toSignout.size(); i++) 
    {
        logOffActiveUser(toSignout.get(i));
    }
}
public void logOffActiveUser(String remoteMachineName) {
    sprogress.setText("Signing active user on "+remoteMachineName+" out...");
    String activeUser = null;
    String command = "quser /server:";
    try {
        String line;
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command + remoteMachineName);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        int lineNumber = 1;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            if (lineNumber == 2) 
            {
                String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
                if (words.length >= 3) 
                {
                    activeUser = words[2];
                } else 
                {
                    activeUser = null;
                }
                break;
            }
            lineNumber++;
        }
        reader.close();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) 
    {
        infoBox("Exception occurred while logging off the active user: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    
    if (activeUser == null) {
        //infoBox("No active user found on " + remoteMachineName); 
        sprogress.setText("No active user found on " + remoteMachineName);
    }
    else
    {
        command = "logoff " + activeUser + " /server:" + remoteMachineName;
        try 
        {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            sprogress.setText("No queued tasks");
            process.waitFor();
        } 
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) 
        {
            infoBox("Exception occurred while logging off the active user: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The label "sprogress" refuses to update before the second method is finished.

Comment: It is not necessary to tell the story about ChatGPT. Focus on the answer, not any story around it.

Comment: @ucczs The story was relevant and inextricably linked to the solution as it is the source of my solution and could help diagnose any weirdness, should any be present. Was your complaint posted out of a distaste for the use of AI help?

Comment: No, not at all. Generative AI like ChatGPT are an amazing tool and massively increases effectiveness.

Comment: @ucczs In my experience it refuses to directly follow instructions and hallucinates. It took a couple hours for me to get the code I needed from ChatGPT because it kept doing its own thing and because I'm not so familiar with the language I needed to test what it gave me if it wasn't so obviously incorrect.